# Is it adequate to use pandas.series.apply() for a webcrawler?

Tags: python, pandas, web-crawler, apply

I imported a dataset from https://www.usgbc.org/projects/list?page=17&keys=Mexico into python-Pandas

This dataset contains buildings with LEED certification (The link provided specifically filters buildings from Mexico)

Each row contains a url with details about each building. I'm interested to webcrawl the url for each building to get the postal code.

I already have a webcrawler to get the data from each page:

```
def webcrawler(x):
    url = x
    try:
        page = requests.get('https://www.usgbc.org/projects/reforma-180')
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    except:           # Regresa false si no logras entrar a la URL
        street = False
        locality = False
        postalcode = False
        country = False
        return

    # get data from tree. Return None if nothing is found 
    try:
        street = ''.join(tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]/text()'))
    except:
        street = None
    try:
        locality = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()')
    except:
        locality = None
    try:
        postalcode = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="postalCode"]/text()')
    except:
        postalcode = None
    try:
        country = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="addressCountry"]/text()')
    except:
        country = None

    return [street, locality, postalcode, country]

# Try it yourself
x = 'https://www.usgbc.org/projects/reforma-180'
y = webcrawler(x)
```

Understanding that the imported dataset contains a column called "Path" containing the link to each building's page, and that the dataset lenght is 2390 rows, my question is:

Is it adequate to use df.Path.apply(webcrawler)?

```
df.Path.apply(webcrawler)
```

My fear is that this will send a lot of requests to the server in a very short span of time, which could be unethical or interpreted as an attack to the server.

Can I get your opinion on this?

Comment: You can add a `time.sleep(0.1)` or something like that if you want to slow down the rate of requests.

Comment: You can just put a delay after your request so requests are not sent too often.

Answer (score -1):

include `from time import sleep` in your imports and add `sleep(0.5)` or so to sleep for half a second between requests.